# Getting different IP addresses in scapy

Tags: python, ip, scapy

```py
from scapy.all import *
sniffdata = sniff(count=10)
sniffdata.summary()
```

Output:

```
Ether / IP / TCP 192.168.1.35:51642 > 20.42.65.85:https A / Raw
Ether / IP / TCP 34.233.187.197:https > 192.168.1.35:51654 A / Raw
Ether / IP / TCP 34.233.187.197:https > 192.168.1.35:51654 A / Raw
```

Scapy is not working, it gives me different IPs. I'm not using any proxies.

Comment: what IP did you expect? IP `192.168.1.35` can be your IP in local network. And when computer send data to internet then first it has to use your local IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line is (I'm assuming from the private address) your machine sending data to 20.42.65.85, the next two are the host 34.233.187.197 sending packets to your IP. See how the from IP matches the to?

These might not be a single session.

Comment: none of these ips belong to me i have checked my ip address i am not using any vpns

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: it was working fine before i don't know what happened i was able to see my ip there and i was able to use the show function i was able to do a lot with scapy

Comment: i am using windows 10

Comment: If you run `ipconfig /a` (I think that's the command, I'm not much of a Windows guy) do you see the 192.168.1.35 address listed?  If not you might be seeing traffic from other hosts on your network segment.

Comment: yes i can see that ip

Comment: Then it is your machine talking to two web servers

Comment: but why i don't see my ip ?

Comment: Why do you think the IP you see in the output of ipconfig is not your IP?

Comment: i understand i thought maybe it is a problem in scapy